# How can I make a Base32 encryption work with the international alphabet/special characters?

Tags: javascript, encoding, decoding, base32

I'm using [this](https://github.com/agnoster/base32-js/edit/master/dist/base32.js) javascript program to try and encode/decode some strings.

This works fine for some strings, but for emails like these I get invalid results:

```
base32.encode("юзер@екзампл.ком.example.com");
```

output:

```
9rvundefinedag206mxundefinedecundefinedw7wxjweundefinedy7gq6ay31dnr6rt9ecdqp
```

input:

```
base32.decode(9rvundefinedag206mxundefinedecundefinedw7wxjweundefinedy7gq6ay31dnr6rt9ecdqpu");
```

results in:

```
"N7ªµÏ\Õ@@5;ªµÏ\×3Uk¹¼?;.;Uk¹¾<.example.com"
```

As you can see, it does not result in the original string when it is decoded. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

`юзер@екзампл.ком.example.com`.
It is 28 characters, not all ASCII (or one byte utf-8).

But several of the input characters are multi-byte utf-8 bytes.
It is 42 utf-8 bytes.

Base32 encoded it should be two characters for each byte in.

`9rvundefinedag206mxundefinedecundefinedw7wxjweundefinedy7gq6ay31dnr6rt9ecdqp`
is 76 character, an obvious error in expected length.

The expected Base32 encoding should be 84 characters.

This is probably because several of the input characters are multi-byte utf-8 bytes.

Something seems to be missing in the question.